# Understanding connection issues when using libimobiledevice for Android to iOS connection

Tags: android, ios, libimobiledevice

I'm trying to build a prototype Android app for connecting my Android device to an iOS device wirelessly. While researching for options, I came across [libimobiledevice library](https://libimobiledevice.org/) which seems like the right fit. I'm currently stuck in what seems like iOS device is receiving the request but rejecting it and that's what I wanted to understand from this forum.

What I have done so far:

- I have packaged libimobiledevice library as an .so file in my Android application and I able to make JNI calls from my Android app to call in methods of the library.
- I'm also packaging in the [libusbmuxd library](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd) and [libplist](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist) as mentioned in the dependencies.
- For protoyping, I'm creating a wifi hotspot from my Android device and connecting the iOS device. I also know the IP addresses of the two devices. I also know that the lockdownd deamon on iOS runs on port 62078. Given the IP address and port, when I make the call to the socket I do see that the idevice_new_with_options -> usbmuxd_get_device -> connect_usbmuxd_socket -> socket_connect is able to reach out to iOS device on the socket. Confirmed by looking at iOS logs

```
lockdownd[70] <Notice>: _receive_message: <private>
symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[120] <Notice>: Data Usage for lockdownd - WiFi in/out: 181637370/198768065, WiFi delta_in/delta_out: 458/0, Cell in/out: 0/0, Cell delta_in/delta_out: 0/0, RNF: 0, subscriber tag: 0
```

- But immediately after this I see that the connection is dropped probably because lockdownd is rejecting it. I see the [this getting triggered](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/master/common/socket.c#L1153) with error 104 which means "Connection reset by peer"

Questions:

- As I understand it, the libimobiledevice is trying to make a TCP/IP connection to iPhone. And once the connection succeeds, I'll be able to use the rest of the capabilities of the library like invoking the mentioned services.
- Is my setup correct or am I missing something? The code compiles and doesn't crash so it feels like I have all the needed dependencies.
- How can I debug this further on iOS side to understant why lockdownd is reseting the connection?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever continue working on this? Is there any code available that captured your last progress for anyone else who would like to continue where you left off?

Answer (score 1):

libimobiledevice depends on usbmux, and for Linux this is not currently working wirelessly. You can overcome this by using the usbmuxd2 re-implementation.

This is my script for getting that full linux implementation up and running on a raspberry Pi. I also have a more user friendly walk through of the same thing right here: [nMirrior](https://www.numerousnetworks.co.uk/guides/nmirror/)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "installing dependencies"

read -p "Do you want to update/install build tools (you need to if this is a new image) (y/n): " -n 1 -r
echo
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    sudo apt-get -q update
    sudo apt-get -q install \
                    build-essential \
                    checkinstall \
                    git \
                    autoconf \
                    automake \
                    libtool-bin
fi


echo "installing libatomic"
sudo apt-get -q install libatomic-ops-dev libatomic1


echo "installing libimobiledevice dependencies"
sudo apt-get -q install \
                libplist-dev \
                libusbmuxd-dev \
                libimobiledevice-dev \
                libusb-1.0-0-dev \
                libplist++-dev \
                libssl-dev \
                usbmuxd \
                udev \
                libavahi-client-dev \
                avahi-utils 



echo "Starting nMirror setup"

# Configure source directories
nMirrorDir=~/nMirror

echo "The applications needed for nMirror will be installed in $nMirror"

libplistDir=$nMirrorDir/libplist
libusbmuxdDir=$nMirrorDir/libusbmuxd
libimobiledeviceDir=$nMirrorDir/libimobiledevice
libgeneralDir=$nMirrorDir/libgeneral
usbmuxd2Dir=$nMirrorDir/usbmuxd2

#Standard libimobiledevice repos
libplistGit=https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist.git
libusbmuxdGit=https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd.git
libimobiledeviceGit=https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.git

#tihmstar repo for usbmuxd2 to support network connection to iDevice
usbmuxd2Git=https://github.com/tihmstar/usbmuxd2.git
libgeneralGit=https://github.com/tihmstar/libgeneral.git



# Create the project directory if it does not exist
mkdir -p $nMirrorDir
cd $nMirrorDir


# Fetch the repos

fetchnext=false
if test -d $libplistDir; then
    read -p "libplist directory exists. Remove and re-fetch new? (y/n): " -n 1 -r
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        rm -rf $libplistDir
        fetchnext=true
    fi
else
    fetchnext=true
fi
if [ "$fetchnext" == true ]; then
    echo "Cloning from git.  1 - libplist"
    cd $nMirrorDir
    git clone --quiet $libplistGit
    cd $libplistDir
    # git checkout 2.2.0 # Cannot go back to the last tag (2.2.0) because usbmuxd2 want 2.2.1 - just get the head for now
fi


if test -d $libusbmuxdDir; then
    read -p "libusbmuxd directory exists. Remove and re-fetch new? (y/n): " -n 1 -r
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        rm -rf $libusbmuxdDir
        fetchnext=true
    fi
else
    fetchnext=true
fi
if [ "$fetchnext" == true ]; then
    echo "Cloning from git.  2 - libusbmuxd (Normal)"
    cd $nMirrorDir
    git clone --quiet $libusbmuxdGit
    cd $libusbmuxdDir
    git checkout 2.0.2
fi

if test -d $libimobiledeviceDir; then
    read -p "libimobiledevice directory exists. Remove and re-fetch new? (y/n): " -n 1 -r
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        rm -rf $libimobiledeviceDir
        fetchnext=true
    fi
else
    fetchnext=true
fi
if [ "$fetchnext" == true ]; then
    echo "Cloning from git.  3 - libimobiledevice"
    cd $nMirrorDir
    git clone --quiet $libimobiledeviceGit
    cd $libimobiledeviceDir
    git checkout 1.3.0
fi


#tihmstar repo for usbmuxd2 to support network connection to iDevice
if test -d $libgeneralDir; then
    read -p "libgeneral directory exists. Remove and re-fetch new? (y/n): " -n 1 -r
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        rm -rf $libgeneralDir
        fetchnext=true
    fi
else
    fetchnext=true
fi
if [ "$fetchnext" == true ]; then
    echo "Cloning from git.  4 - libgeneral (tihmstar Experimental repo tag 55)"
    cd $nMirrorDir
    git clone --quiet $libgeneralGit
    cd $libgeneralDir
    git checkout 55
fi


if test -d $usbmuxd2Dir; then
    read -p "usbmuxd2 directory exists. Remove and re-fetch new? (y/n): " -n 1 -r
    echo
    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
    then
        rm -rf $usbmuxd2Dir
        fetchnext=true
    fi
else
    fetchnext=true
fi
if [ "$fetchnext" == true ]; then
    echo "Cloning from git.  5 - usbmuxd2 (tihmstar Eperimental repo)"
    cd $nMirrorDir
    git clone --quiet $usbmuxd2Git
    cd $usbmuxd2Dir
    git submodule init
    git submodule update
fi

#build stage

cd $libplistDir
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install

cd $libusbmuxdDir
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install

cd $libimobiledeviceDir
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install

sudo ldconfig

#configure Avahi for zeroconf as per https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=267113
#Note: Zeroconf may not be desirable - use with caution
cd $nMirrorDir

#create avahi patch
tee avahi.patch <<EOF
--- /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf 2021-08-16 23:59:16.917672251 +0100
+++ /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon_usbmuxd.conf 2021-08-17 09:45:02.096575347 +0100
@@ -20,7 +20,7 @@
 
 [server]
 #host-name=foo
-#domain-name=local
+domain-name=local
 #browse-domains=0pointer.de, zeroconf.org
 use-ipv4=yes
 use-ipv6=yes
@@ -46,8 +46,8 @@
 #disable-user-service-publishing=no
 #add-service-cookie=no
 #publish-addresses=yes
-publish-hinfo=no
-publish-workstation=no
+publish-hinfo=yes
+publish-workstation=yes
 #publish-domain=yes
 #publish-dns-servers=192.168.50.1, 192.168.50.2
 #publish-resolv-conf-dns-servers=yes
EOF

cd /etc
sudo patch -p2 < $nMirrorDir/avahi.patch

#enable the avahi-daemon
systemctl list-unit-files avahi-daemon.service
#activate/enable the avahi-daemon.service
sudo systemctl enable avahi-daemon.service
sudo systemctl start avahi-daemon.service
sudo systemctl restart avahi-daemon.service
#enable ssh service
sudo systemctl enable ssh.service
sudo systemctl start ssh.service
#avahi-browse -a 


# if using gcc: the patch below works to include -latomic 
# if using clang: make CXX=clang++

cd $libgeneralDir
./autogen.sh
make CFLAGS="-g -O2 -std=c11 -latomic" LDFLAGS=-latomic
sudo make install

sudo ldconfig

cd $usbmuxd2Dir

#create log patch
#cassure only needed for versions after 55 - probably remove this as checkout is fixed to 55
tee log.patch <<EOF
--- a/configure.ac
+++ b/configure.ac
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@ case $host_os in
         have_mdns="yes"
         ;;
   *)
-        LDFLAGS+=" -lstdc++fs"
+        LDFLAGS+="-latomic -lstdc++fs"
         ;;
 esac
 
EOF

git apply log.patch
./autogen.sh
make
sudo make install

sudo ldconfig


# get the BT PAN up and running
sudo apt-get install bluez-tools

sudo tee /etc/systemd/network/pan0.netdev <<EOF
[NetDev]
Name=pan0
Kind=bridge
EOF
 
 
sudo tee /etc/systemd/network/pan0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=pan0
[Network]
Address=172.20.1.1/24
DHCPServer=yes
EOF
 
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/bt-agent.service <<EOF
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth Auth Agent
 
[Service]
#ExecStart=/usr/bin/bt-agent -c NoInputNoOutput
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/yes | /usr/bin/bt-agent --capability=NoInputNoOutput' #autoaccept
Type=simple
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
 
sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/bt-network.service <<EOF
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth NEP PAN
After=pan0.network
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bt-network -s nap pan0
Type=simple
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl enable bt-agent
sudo systemctl enable bt-network
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl start bt-agent
sudo systemctl start bt-network

sudo bt-adapter --set Discoverable 1

# list devices. Need to ask the user to connect via USB the first time using idevicesyslog. Then make the BT PAN connection and connect via idevicesyslog -n

/usr/local/bin/idevice_id
```